# Why we can't write class Child implements AnyInterface extends Base in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

When we are extending an class and implementing an interface we write it as-

```
public interface AnyInterface{ ---- }

public class Base{  -- }

public class Child extends Base implements AnyInterface{ ---- }
```

now my question is why cant we write it as -

```
public class child implements AnyInterface extends Base{ --- }
```

Comment: ...because that's the order that was decided upon in the language specification, and hence that's the order that the compiler looks for.

Comment: yeah but i was looking for more logical answer which i have got from answers. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may extend only one class but may implement one to many interfaces. In that case, it would be more reader-friendly to have the extend-ing first before the implement-ing stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's not the syntax the language chose.

What you are proposing would only add to the complexity of the language, not to mention reducing its readability.  Why have more than on syntax when one works?

Answer (score 0):

because classes are there for individual operation where as the interface are there for multiple operation as we are defining the services in the child classes.so there is no chance for ambiguity .The single responsibility principle states that class should do one thing only. Multiple inheritance is highly correlated with probability of multiple responsibilities.